# MS SQL Server String to Datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I have below string of date time

```
2017-09-06 00:36:32.473491+05:30
```

I want to store this date time into MS SQL Server table and my datatype for this column is `datetime`.

I tried CAST but it gives me the following error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
So please help me to fix this.
I am using `MS SQL Server 2014`

Comment: How do you import it? Maybe you should parse it there to DateTime. In C# f.e. it's easy: `DateTime.Parse("2017-09-06 00:36:32.473491+05:30")` works as it is.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am not using any programming language. I try `select CAST('2017-09-06 00:36:32.473491+05:30' AS DateTime) as date_time;` in MS SQL Server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a super easy alternative...

```
SELECT CAST(left('2017-09-06 00:36:32.473491+05:30',19) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip out the milliseconds and time offset before you can `CAST` to `DATETIME`.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100) = '2017-09-06 00:36:32.473491+05:30'
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), @s, 121)
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(19), @s, 121) AS DATETIME)
```

However, if your datatype was `DATETIME2` then you wouldn't need to

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100) = '2017-09-06 00:36:32.473491+05:30' SELECT
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), @s, 121) SELECT CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), @s,
121) AS DATETIME2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try [this](http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date)
CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-09-06 00:36:32.473') do the job but not with your precision!